# How to get user data from HTML form?

Tags: html, rust, handlebars.js, rocket

I am writing a Rust web app using Rocket and Handlebars.

In my main.rs, I render a Handlebars template. In that template, I have a form. When the user enters in their information and presses "submit", I want to send that user input to another template.

**index.hbs, simplified**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id = myForm>
            ...
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**main.rs, simplified**

```rust
fn index() -> Template {
    context = context();
    Template::render("index", &context)
}

fn main() {
    rocket.ignite()
    .mount("/", routes![index, ...])
    .attach(Template::fairing())
    .launch();
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? It's hard to help without a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I'll update the question.

Comment: I've updated the question to show basically what I've done. I'm not sure how to conceptually get the user input from the form in index.hbs.

I would theoretically like to get the user input from the form, and then call another template (say, index2.hbs) from index.hbs and pass it as context... *or do something similar, to that effect.*

Comment: @DarrelGulseth please check the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Code Flow:**
When the user request for `/` root route then we render the index template which contains the form, then user fills the form detail and submit the form which raise post request to `/` root route where we check if user has filled all the information through the form struct that will be initialized by the submitted values, if the values are correct then we render the home template passing the initialized form instance or else we render the index template

**main.rs**

```rs
#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use rocket_dyn_templates::Template;
use rocket::form::Form;
use rocket::serde::Serialize;

#[get("/")]
fn index() -> Template {
    let mut context: HashMap<&str, &str> = HashMap::new();
    Template::render("index", &context)
}

#[derive(Debug, FromForm, Serialize)]
struct Task<'r> {
   description: &'r str,
   completed: bool
}

#[post("/", data = "<task>")]
fn new(task: Form<Task<'_>>) -> Template {
    if task.description.is_empty() {
        Template::render("index", &*task)
    } else {
        Template::render("home", &*task)
    }
}

#[get("/home")]
fn home() -> Template {
    let mut context: HashMap<&str, &str> = HashMap::new();
    Template::render("home", &context)
}

#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    rocket::build()
    .mount("/", routes![index, new, home])
    .attach(Template::fairing())
}
```

**index.html.hbs**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="myForm" method="POST">
            <input name="description" type="text" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**home.html.hbs**

```
Task Description: {{ description }}
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "s71358173"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
rocket = { version = "0.5.0-rc.1", features = ["json"] }
rocket_dyn_templates = { version = "0.1.0-rc.1", features = ["handlebars", "tera"] }
serde = {version = "1.0", features = ["derive"]}
serde_json = {version = "1.0"}
```

Note: Context value are accessible inside template which we used to print the description.

Comment: Can you please expalin this to me? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: @DarrelGulseth added explanation please let me know if anything i may have missed or something is not understandable.

Comment: @DarrelGulseth please let me know if there is some issue in answer